# The type name crystal report does not exist in the type

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, crystal-reports

This line is not compiling

```
this.CrystalReport11 = new ExpenseReport.CrystalReport1();
```

I am on visual studio 2010 and am having this problem when adding a crystal report to my app. I have changed the framework from .net 4 client profile to just .net 4 and I have added this line

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" >
```

to the app.config but still have the problem. This is not happening when I create a new app from scratch.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What error message(s) do you get?

Comment: The type name 'CrystalReport1' does not exist in the type 'ExpenseReport.ExpenseReport'

Comment: Show your code.  It sounds like you have some misplaced curly braces.

Comment: Its just this one line in the designer. I don't believe my code is related because it should launch the report even if I take out the code. I can build a new project with a crystal report and it runs fine even if there is no code telling it to display data. If I remove the code in my project so it is a similar scenario it still doesnt compile

Comment: Is it possible it is related to changing my project to .net without client profile so late in its development? Usually I switch this immediately when creating an app with a crystal report

Comment: You say if you take that line out, it still won't compile? What's the new error you get if you take the line out?

Comment: The line that is erroring is auto-generated by the designer when I create the crystal report. If I take that line out the design view of the form will crash even when im not debugging. My code does not matter because it is only in a click event. Thats why i do not believe the issue is with the code.

Comment: The only way I found to fix this problem was to start the project over and change the project to the full .net 4 framework from the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this on the SAP forum as well and they could not offer a solution either. The only way I found to fix this issue was to rebuild the application and changing it to full dotnet 4 framework from the start. It seems that working on the app and switching it from client profile later on is what caused the problem.

Solution: If you are going to use crystal reports change your framework before you start your app!